# jquery dialog form with asp:hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, dialog

I have an issue in implementing the JQuery dialog with asp.net form. When I click on `#hlChangePassword` nothing happens. This is my code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#hlChangePassword').click(function () {
            var dlg = jQuery('div#ChangePass').dialog({
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {},
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                }
            });
            dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
        });
    });

</script>
```

html

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlChangePassword" 
runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">Change Password</asp:HyperLink>

<div id="ChangePass" style="display:none;">
//The content
</div>
```

I don't know what is the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User event.preventDefault(); to prevent the post back as follows

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#hlChangePassword').click(function (event) {
        var dlg = jQuery('div#ChangePass').dialog({
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {},
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            }
        });
        dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
        event.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

As `hlChangePassword` is a server control so it will post back. to overcome this you should use `event.preventDefault`.
Also you are using `id` selector which can change at run-time due to master page or user-control. So use server id or static id for the link as follows if you are using asp.net 4.0 or above as follows

```
ClientIDMode="Static"


<asp:HyperLink ID="hlChangePassword"  ClientIDMode="Static"
 runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">Change Password</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: what is the id of your hyper link in the browser?? Is it same

Comment: I guess the problem related to the master page. using the content form from a master page. would you please explain it more?

Comment: exactly the same id in the browser !

Comment: which version of asp.net r u using

Answer (score 0):

Bingo...
    script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js">
add above line it wont work without ui.js.